# Laravel: view not found

Tags: apache2, laravel-4

I'm developing an internal site using Laravel 4, I have everyone working on my laptop (Windows & Apache).

I've now moved the site to a Turnkey Linux 13 VM for beta testing and have encountered the following problem:

The home page loads fine.
When I come to load the About page (or any other page) I get "requested URL /internal/about not found".

- The Laravel config is exactly the same.
- Apache's document root is set to: /var/laravel/public.
- Apache gives the following error in the logs:
  "File does not exist: /var/laravel/public/internal"

Yet the Laravel config is specifying the default view directory and the home page loads fine.

Comment: What's the url of the about page /about or /internal/about? Try to go to `http://your-site/index.php/about` or `http://your-site/index.php/internal/about`.

Comment: Thanks @AntonioCarlosRibeiro, yes, it's a mod_rewrite issue, I just haven't had the chance to post an answer yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was an Apache config issue, mod_rewrite wasn't enabled (it was on my Windows laptop), simply enabling this resolved the issue.